# How to embed C dynamic libraries into Go binary

Tags: c, go, portability, cgo

I have a Golang project which uses some C libraries from another team in my company which come with shared objects and would be very difficult to compile statically.
I would like to keep the binary for my project portable, so I want to use `import "embed"` to keep the shared objects in the binary and then dump them into a temp dir when the program starts, but before the C part of my project loads.

I can probably compile the part of my project that uses the C code into a Go plugin and then doing all the embed stuff in the main binary before it loads that plugin, but I feel like there's an easier way that I'm missing.

Is there any way to stop Go from trying to load C dynamic libraries before I unpack them? Or maybe on the C side stop it from trying to load them so early?

Comment: Go doesn't load the shared libraries, shared libraries are loaded into memory by the OS (or more specifically the dynamic linker) before the main process starts. Can you not statically link the libraries?

Comment: I think you can link shared library or static library with cgo and -L option in golang. Make sure the library path is existed.

Comment: @PeterLai I currently have that working in my private build with shared libraries, but before I release it to the rest of my team, I need the binbary to be portable.

Comment: @JimB as I said in the question, it isn't straightforward to get static versions of the libraries. Still, your comment is useful in that I think this means I'll have to either go with the plugin method or have a bootstrap phase where the normal executable is embedded into the bootstrap executable along with the libraries and all the bootstrap does is unpack things and call the main executable.